# Shiny (R): Download selection in selectInput to local machine

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app where users can view a list of files in the directory, select one of the files, and then download it to their computer. I may be over-complicating this, but I can't seem to find a solution.

**ui.R**

```
filenames <- list.files(path=".",pattern="\\.txt")
shinyUI(navbarPage("Download page",
tabPanel("Download",
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("filenames", "Select the file you want to download:", filenames), downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
),

mainPanel(
p("Preview of sheet."),
tableOutput('table')
)))))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$filenames,
          filenames)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file)
    }
  )})
```

When I run the app, I can view the list of files in my directory, but the download function does not result in the selected file being downloaded.

Comment: Are you trying to download the list of the files (filenames) ? Because that's what you are pointing to in your server.R !

Comment: I would like the server to recognize that the user has selected one of the files in filename (any one of them), and then download that file locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a bunch of 'csv' files in your working directory the code below  will list and preview the 'csv' files and download the selected file to your desired directory.

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Download page",
tabPanel("Download",
sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
           selectInput("filenames", "Select the file you want to download:", list.files(pattern = '.csv')), 
           downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')),
      mainPanel(
         p("Preview of sheet."),
      tableOutput('table')
)))))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$filenames,
           filenames)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    read.csv(input$filenames, header=TRUE)
  })


  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {input$filenames},
    content = function(file) {write.csv(read.csv(input$filenames, header=TRUE),file)}
  )})
```