# Is there any way to download a data into a particular folder in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to download a data frame as a .csv format into a particular folder. But in my case whenevver I click on download button the data get downloaded into 'download' folder of C drive.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data download app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to display and download selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also tried the same for a plot. I used `file.copy()` to save the file into the desired location but it's also not working.

Comment: Does this post address your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865635/r-shiny-downloading-a-csv-to-the-working-directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your file into a desired location, I think this command should work:
`output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(setwd(),input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")`

The function setwd() allows you to write a path. So put your folder between (), and pay attention about your actual working directory, by using getwd().
Hope it will help.